# How to throw exception from a static method using jmockit

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, jmockit

I am writing jmockit testcase for a class which calls a static method from different class.

I want to throw exception when the static method is called

```
class ClassToBeTested {
      methodToBeMocked(){
      if(ClasswithStaticMethod.staticMethod()){
      }
}
}
```

On ClassToBeTested.methodToBeMocked() I want exception to be thrown from staticMethod.

How can this be achieved using jmockit?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using below approach:

```
public void testMethodToBeMocked(@Mocked final ClasswithStaticMethod classwithStaticMethod){
        new Expectations() {
            {
                classwithStaticMethod.staticMethod()
                result =  new Exception();
            }
        };
        ClassToBeTested.methodToBeMocked();
    }
```